# Pulsar botón automáticamente

Tags: javascript, ajax, botón, whatsapp

Tengo un script de JS que manda un mensaje aprovechando la API de WhatsApp proporcionada por la web.

Pregunta el mensaje a enviar y conecta con `api.whatsapp.com/send?phone`.

```
function initPagina(){
    var texto = prompt("Mensaje a enviar", "");
    if(texto==""){
        alert("Por favor introduzca un mensaje a enviar.");
        initPagina();
    }
    else{
        var telef = "[numeroaenviar]";
        window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+telef+"&text="+texto+"","_self");
    }
}
```

Me gustaría hacer que en cuanto se conecte, espere unos 5 min, y pulse el boton que hay en esa pagina con el `id: action-button`.

He encontrado este código pero no sirve, ya que por lo que he leido, sirve solo para botones de tu propio programa o página.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // indicamos que se ejecuta la funcion a los 5 segundos de haberse
        // cargado la pagina
        setTimeout(clickbutton,5000);
        function clickbutton(){
            // simulamos el click del mouse en el boton del formulario
            $("#action-button").click();
            alert("Aqui llega");  //Debugger
        }
 });
```

Al alert no llega tampoco.

¿Se podría hacer lo que estoy pidiendo?,¿o es imposible?

PD: Vengo de programar en C++, Java, Swift etc. De web, pocas nociones, algun consejo para mi? sobretodo JQuery y AJAX como trabajan con PHP.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: 5 min o 5 segundos?

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra la consola del navegador? Si no se ejecuta el `alert`, es que la función `clickbutton` no se está llamando.

Comment: puedes extender más los elementos DOM y las páginas donde las estás llamando? por lo que veo estás utilizando un iframe, o estás tratando de editar una web, de ser así me temo que no es tan sencillo debido al [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), el navegador prohibirá cualquier manipulación a sitios ajenos de tu dominio. En orden para poder hacerlo deberás crear un plugin para el navegador

Comment: Buenas, mi problema es que el window.open llama a api.whatsapp.com, que envia un mensaje a un telefono, y se lo paso en la url, ya que funciona. El problema surge que en api.whatsapp.com.... hay un botón de Enviar, ESE es el que quiero pulsar automáticamente, el #action-button NO está en mi pagina, sino en la del window.open(la que le digo que abra)

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias por el consejo, voy a ver que error da la consola. No lo he mirado.

Comment: Ese último detalle es lo que nos faltaba para entender lo que pasa, edita la pregunta y añade que estás trabajando sobre otra ventana

Comment: Ya he dicho que no puedes modificar el comportamiento de una web desde distintos dominios, los navegadores solo permiten scripting con la política [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_politica), además whatsapp utiliza CORS lo cual implica que incluso utilizando un proxy no podrás modificar el contenido (pseudo domain hijacked). La única forma de hacer lo que planteas es a través de plugins de navegadores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el objeto document que estás usando es el de la ventana actual. Si quieres trabajar sobre una ventana hija tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
let hija=window.open(...);
```

Y entonces acceder al documento de la ventana hija:

```
$(hija.document).ready(function() {
  // indicamos que se ejecuta la funcion a los 5 segundos de haberse
  // cargado la pagina


  function clickbutton() {
    // simulamos el click del mouse en el boton del formulario
    $("#action-button").click();
  }
  $('#action-button').on('click',function() {
    console.log('action button clicked');
  });

  setTimeout(clickbutton, 5000);
});
```

Comment: me temo que el op está modificando el contenido de una página en distinto dominio, y por la politica `same-origin` el navegador lo impide, la única forma en que el op pueda hacer lo que desea es 1) crear un plugin para el navegador y registrarlo al dominio objetivo, 2) pedirle al dueño del dominio que agregue a su servidor respuestas CORS, que permitan la manipulación del sitio (en este caso es whatsapp así que esta opción es inviable) , 3) modificar el navegador para que no utilize la política same-origin (lo cuál no es viable, ya que todos los usuarios tendrían que modifcar sus navegadores).

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo que es imposible actuar sobre una pagina en distinto dominio. Gracias a todos por las respuestas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Mi consejo, quita todo el otro javascript y deja solamente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // indicamos que se ejecuta la funcion a los 5 segundos de haberse
  // cargado la pagina
  setTimeout(clickbutton, 5000);

  function clickbutton() {
    // simulamos el click del mouse en el boton del formulario
    $("#action-button").click();
    alert("Aqui llega"); //Debugger
  }
  $('#action-button').on('click',function() {
    console.log('action button clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="action-button">hola soy el action button, vengo a flotar</button>
```

Que, por cierto, funciona. Luego ve añadiendo los scripts adicionales hasta que falle de nuevo. Es como operar con TDD salvo que este sería Workaround Driven Development.

No está de más preguntar: no será que tienes la función `clickbutton` redeclarada en otro lado?

Esto no responde realmente la pregunta. Siéntanse libres de votar en contra hasta el infinito y más allá.